# I am trying to disable dates of particular days in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, calendar, datepickerdialog

I am trying to disable dates of particular days in DatePickerDialog in android, I know how to set Min and Max limit, but is there a way to disable particular dates of a month in the same

Code:

```
  public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        // Subtract 6 days from Calendar updated date
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);

        // Set the Calendar new date as minimum date of date picker
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());




        // Return the DatePickerDialog
        return  dpd;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        // Do something with the chosen date
        TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);

        // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();

        // Format the date using style and locale
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);

        // Display the chosen date to app interface
        tv.setText(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, date picker doesn't give you such flexibility. You either have to create a custom date picker view yourself or check for date validity after date is selected in OnDateSet() method

Comment: is there any site where i can get custom datepicker?

Comment: create yourself. update this question if you find any problem but write some code first before asking for help.